# Não consigo remover READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android

[image]

Essa permissão não esta no meu AndroidManifest mesmo assim quando vou fazer o upload para a play store aparece essa mensagem da imagem, sendo que meu app não usa esse tipo de dado, pfv me ajudem!

Comment: Quais valores do seu `minSdkVersion ` e `targetSdkVersion `?

Comment: minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 26

Answer (score 1):

Depois de um pesquisa, consegui encontrar uma solução que é bem simples. Vou postar aqui casa alguém passe pelo mesmo problema.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="seu pacote">`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove" />
```

adicione isso ao manifest.